# Nancy DLLs blocked after downloading from Internet

Tags: .net, nancy

I am using `Nancy 1.4.3` in a `.NET 4.6.1 Console Application`. After building the code in Release mode, I zipped the files and uploaded to OneDrive. When my friend downloaded and extracted the files, the below 3 DLLs were **blocked**.

```
 1. Nancy.dll
 2. Nancy.Hosting.Self.dll 
 3. Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll
```

For the EXE to work correctly, either the user should unblock the zip file before extraction or he should unblock the 3 DLLs after extraction. None of the other DLLs are blocked. The EXE is signed using a Code Signing Certificate.

The **Zone.Identifier** attribute can be removed programmatically by [Understanding The Internet File Blocking and Unblocking](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-the-internet-file-blocking-and-unblocking).

My concern is why only the `Nancy.*.dlls` are blocked and other DLLs are not blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can answer your question, it depends on your friends configuration.

It might be because NancyFx dll are not signed.

See https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Statement-on-strong-naming